# Can I change an XText object into a string with character references and entities resolved?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Given this XML:

```
<element>Circles &amp; boxes</element>
```

What I would like to do is store the string value of the element as a string, with all of the character references and entities resolved to their equivalent unicode characters.  So, for this element, I would want "Circles & Boxes."

When I do this (text is an XText object representing the text node):

```
string textvalue = text.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```

I get "Circles & Boxes," which is not what I want.

Is this possible?

Comment: I think you forgot to escape something: you say 'I get "Circles & Boxes," which is not what I want.' which is actually what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using:

```
string textvalue = text.Value;
```